# Spring JPA está tentando inserir registro com uma chave já existente

Tags: spring

Tenho uma entidade que já possui registros no banco de dados (totalizando 20 registros).
A coluna referente a chave primaria dessa entidade está definida como `SERIAL`, no banco de dados **postgres**.
Este é meu mapeamento da entidade:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo", schema = "public")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FooEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="foo_seq", sequenceName = "foo_seq", initialValue = 20, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "foo_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
}
```

Fiz uma query para buscar os sequences existentes no meu banco e encontrei a sequence foo_seq criada ao inserir a tabela.

No meu service, ao tentar chamar o repositório para salvar os dados da entidade, é retornado que a chave gerada já possui correspondência no banco de dados:

```
    FooEntity fooEntity = FooEntity.builder()
      .id(null)
      .build();
FooEntity savedEntity = fooRepository.save(fooEntity);
```

Estou recebendo:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key
> value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"   Detail: Key (id)=(5)
> already exists.

A cada tentativa de salvar, é incrementado um número na chave, porém ele não está seguindo a sequência que eu defini (iniciando com 20, para pular os registros já existentes).

Tentei com algumas outras alternativas de strategy, como: `AUTO`, `IDENTITY`.
Com a "`AUTO`", é retornado um erro informando que a relação "`hibernate_sequence`" não existe;
Com a "`Identity`" também tenta inserir um registro iniciando com id 1, conflitando com o registro já existente no banco.

Qual a alternativa neste caso?

Comment: Você tentou mudar o tipo da coluna no banco de dados? Tenta colocar ele como "integer" ao invés de "serial".

Comment: @zn43 porque eu deveria fazer isso?

Comment: colocando `serial` no banco você deixa a cargo do Postgres gerar o ID, porém como você já colocou `@GeneratedValue`, que faz o Hibernate gerar o ID, deve estar dando algum conflito

Comment: Acessando o Postgres via linha de comando ou PGAdmin, execute `ALTER SEQUENCE foo_seq RESTART WITH 20;` para restartar o sequence e veja se resolve.